# How to populate dropdown menu based on rails database values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu

I have a scaffolded project in ruby on rails in which I populated a players and scores. I would like to have a dropdown menu that is populated by the players dropdown menu.

The process is, first a player is made on the players page, then I go to the scores page, fill a new score, and then the dropdown menu will have a ll the players signed up already, input the score, then create a new player with the score associated with it.

(bonus, I would like to integrate these functions (combine player and score information into one form)

Form for scores:

```
<%= form_for(@score) do |f| %>
  <% if @score.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@score.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this score from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @score.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lowest_time %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :lowest_time %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :player_id %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :player_id %>
    <%= @score.player %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Form for players

```
<%= form_for(@player) do |f| %>
  <% if @player.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@player.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this player from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @player.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I do have a players model with has_many :scores and a scores model with belongs_to :player

The way I have it now is that the player id is showing, but that is not practical in terms of the user would have to input the id_number of the player...

Any help would be appreciated! If there are is any needed additional code to show what my problem is, let me know.

Comment: You need to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :score` in the player model. Here's more info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html .. https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon .. http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `scores` form, instead of inputting the player id, use the Rails `select` helper:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :player_id %><br>
  <%= f.select(:player_id, Player.all.pluck(:name, :id), @score.player_id %>
</div>
```

Check out the [Rails docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) for more info.